# Issue with displaying site on mobile , despite column properties scaling properly at various desktop resolutions/dimensions

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

First, here's the link to the page:
https://daniel-scott.herokuapp.com/index

So basically, if I have it running on desktop in "phone" mode (just a narrow browser window on one side), everything works perfectly, and the layout is as it should be on mobile.

HOWEVER,

When I actually open the page on mobile Chrome, I get no such mobile site. I literally just get the desktop site zoomed out heavily.

Am I missing some sort of flag? I'm pretty new to this.

Everything is outlined above. Beyond that, I tried re-pushing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `head`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

You can find more information about [what this tag does on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

Comment: No problem, feel free to mark this as as answered if it helped.